# module 'keras.api._v2.keras.experimental' has no attribute 'PeepholeLSTMCell'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I tried to install tensorflow_federated in google colab. I used

```
pip install --quiet tensorflow-federated-nightly
import tensorflow-federated as tff
```

and it worked. but now when I try to import it get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.experimental' has no attribute 'PeepholeLSTMCell'
```

I don't know why I get this error, because I didn't have any problem before.

I also used the following code to install tensorflow-federated:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated-nightly
```

but I get the same error.

How do I fix it?

My versions are:

`tensorflow 2.8.0`,
`keras 2.8.0`,
`tensorflow-federated-nightly  0.19.0.dev20220218`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To use TensorFlow Federated with TensorFlow 2.8.0, please try the newly released version of TFF `0.20.0` [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-federated/0.20.0/), [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.20.0).

The `tensorflow-federated-nightly` package depends on the nightly versions of TensorFlow (`tf-nightly`), Keras (`keras-nightly`) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

got solution using this : from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you plz explain how would ImageDataGenerator solve the problem?